# PHP searching through .txt file to find specific word

Tags: php, plugins, file-get-contents, explode

I have a .txt file that has hundreds of lines in it an example of a few lines are:

```
<add key="COSTBREAK:White Deal Timber:.31" value="None|FUTUREMARGIN~61" />
<add key="COSTBREAK:White Deal Timber:.51" value="None|FUTUREMARGIN~60" />
<add key="COSTBREAK:White Deal Timber:1.00" value="None|FUTUREMARGIN~53" />
<add key="COSTBREAK:White Deal Timber:2.00" value="None|FUTUREMARGIN~46" />
```

but in the same document I also have lines that read:

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="SETTINGS:CONNECTIONS:SECUREFTP" value="FALSE" />
```

I am trying to write a php file that can seperate every line/word and only output the lines with 'COSTBREAK' in them. I was wondering is this possible to do and if it is any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will store every line, where "COSTBREAK" is included, into $result.

```
$file = file("filename.txt");

$result = null;
foreach ($file as $row) {
  if (strpos($row, "COSTBREAK") !== false) {
    $result .= $row;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help but when I echo $result it only displays '$result' instead of the actual row. Any ideas on how to solve this would help massively ? thank you

Comment: Did you use exactly the same code as above? Or are you doing something else with $result before the output?

Comment: This is what i've done :                                                                               $file = file("wp-content\plugins\Margin-Master-Plugin\MarginMasterFields.txt");

$result = null;
foreach ($file as $row) {
  if (strpos($row, "COSTBREAK") !== false) {
    $result .= $row;
    
    return $result;
  }

Comment: Theres a return statement inside the if-clause. If this is part of a function and you want to return the complete $result, then you have to put the return statement at the end of the code, outside of the foreach-loop.

Comment: when I put it outside of the for-each loop nothing is returned ?

Comment: The return statement only works in the context of a function. Are you using the code inside a function? If so, then you have to put the return statement at the end of the function, outside of the foreach loop.